# Loading/Updating new data to a webpage and using Knockout to dynamically update UI

Tags: javascript, json, rest, knockout.js

Working with the dynamic JavaScript Technology called [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), I would like to send new data to my webpage and ask Knockout to do the dynamic UI update for me.

The below example shows a very simple webpage that shows two Scores (P1 and P2). The JavaScript creates a ViewModel() using Knockout. Unfortunately, I only achieved this by providing a JSON-data property. And I don't know how to dynamically load and also dynamically update new score-data.

Now my question: How can I "inject" (i.e. load at first and update at any time) new data to my webpage and Knockout would update the Scores UI dynamically ?

I guess, I would need some sort of...

a) $.getJSON(".... for the initial loading!

b) Post-request (REST) call from anywhere for the data-update

But how do I do a) and b) ???
Thanks for any help on this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>iKK_ScoreMirror</title>
</head>

<script type='text/javascript' src='Knockout/knockout-3.4.2.js'></script>

<body>

<h3>Game</h3>

    <p>Score P1 =  <span data-bind="text: scoreP1"></span> </p>
    <p>Score P2 =  <span data-bind="text: scoreP2"></span> </p>

</body>

<script>

    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        // !!!!!!! Here is the json-data given fix
        var jsonData = {
            sP1: 13,
            sP2: 23
        };

        self.scoreP1 = ko.observable(jsonData.sP1)
        self.scoreP2 = ko.observable(jsonData.sP2)
    };

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?  here is a runnable fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/ca0xv62w/2/

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.scoreP1 = ko.observable('13')
  self.scoreP2 = ko.observable('23')
  self.loadDataFromServer = function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(data)
      },
      url: '/echo/json/',
      success: function(response) {
       self.scoreP1(response.sP1);
       self.scoreP2(response.sP2);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Kind of :) I do not want to make the data update through a button from within the webpage's UI- but instead, I would like to dynamically update the viewmodel-data through another App (i.e. most likely with a POST-request). How would I do that ?

Comment: so are you looking for a push notification that knockout will respond to?

Comment: Yes, I think that comes close. All I want to achieve is to have several clients looking at their browsers and what they see is an automatic update of their UI-content. The UI-change shall be initiated by an App through some sort of REST-post to the host-server of the webpage (or as you mention, through a push notification of some sort). How would you do that ?

Comment: here is a solution using Microsoft's web api for your rest service.  https://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/native-html5-push-notifications-with-asp-net-web-api-and-knockout-js/

Comment: Thank you, Bryan - I'll have a look at it.